# Why industry is not using Peak current mode control by sensing the switch current in Interleaved Boost PFC Converters?

Tags: current, control

Interleaved Boost PFC is the common topology for power converters. If we sense the switch current in Interleaved Boost PFC, then we have to use Peak Current Mode Control, then why is the industry using Average current mode Control? Why are they not preferring to use Peak Mode Control?
As in this, UG-2021-06- The 5 kW, two-channel, interleaved CCM PFC EVAL board using UCC28070 is an Average Current mode Controller.
I have gone through multiple industrial notes, they are sensing Switch Current and using Average Current mode Control. Can you tell me why Infineon preferred to use Avg. Mode Control instead of Peak Mode Control in Interleaved Boost PFC?

Comment: Maybe because using average produces a cleaner power factor correction with fewer spurious harmonics.

Comment: But to use average current mode control, we have to sense inductor current. How we can use the average current mode while sensing the switch current?